# Oracle Session Numbers Going Crazy - What is the best tool for Analyzing Unclosed Cursors?

Tags: java, oracle, session, analyzer

We have an application (web applications and web services -> commons-dbcp -> dbs) which eats Oracle db sessions. Our system engineers cries like Gluttony Gluttony, stop their sentences with a "UNCLOSED CURSORS !!!" and blames the application behind which is mainly written with Java. We software developers desperately try to find unclosed statements, result sets, connections. 
So far we use

- findbugs
- codepro analytix.

As far as I know they use static code analysis and we can not find major leaks.

**My first question is there any other tool that can trace the unclosed cursors?**

**My second question is there a monitoring tool which can analyze a running JVM and find unclosed cursors in a running JVM?**

I know similar questions have been asked on SO. I am desperate enough for losing some SO points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying v$open_cursor migh be helpful.
See this thread: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:685336504294